# Countably infinite set bounded between 0 and 2

Tags: real-analysis

I have been trying to come up with an example of a Countably infinite set bounded between 2 natural numbers that have a greater distance than 1 between them. Is this possible?

Comment: Provided you allow rationals (or reals), of course it is possible.

Comment: Do you know the solution for when the distance is not greater than $1$?

Comment: Greater distance than 1 between… what? Between every pair of elements of the set, or between the natural numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facts:

- The rational numbers are countably infinite.
- The rational numbers are dense in the real number line.
- Any interval of positive length will contain infinitely many elements of a dense subset.
- Any subset of a countably infinite set will again be countably infinite or finite.

> $\Bbb Q\cap [a,a+b]$ where $b\geq 2$ will always be infinite in size and countable and have the desired properties.

Answer (score -2):

A set like that can't be in size bigger then 3 because if you have 4 number and the distance is no less then 1 so you have interval from size bigger 3 in your set.